# Why do i need to enable id token in azure app registration even though i will use authorization code flow?

Tags: azure, authentication, openid-connect, azureportal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtKoU.png)

Why do i need to enable id token check box if in msal response type is code

Answer (score 0):

msal response type is code which will be used to get id token from token endpoint.
ID token is an artifact that proves that the user has been authenticated